# Joining Nodes Alters Curve Type

Tags: inkscape

I have occasionally run into a problem in Inkscape where I am trying to join two nodes that are snapped on top of each other in order to combine curves, but doing so alters the curve type of one of the joined curves.

For example, I have two curves here
[image: Before nodes are joined]

But when I join the two overlapping nodes at the right angle, the lines in the round curve become "rigid", and I don't know how to prevent or modify this behavior.

[image]

Is there a way to stop this behavior?
[Here is an example file with the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G0Ps1YRtUX8Al2JtfOISEGkJ13V_Buky/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I can't replicate the problem, so there must be something you are doing that you have not mentioned. [See example here](https://imgur.com/a/dc58x).  Perhaps make sure you have snap to nodes enabled so that the nodes are exactly placed on top of each other.  That's all I can think of without more info.

Comment: @BillyKerr I just realized I should have added an example file of the problem I was having. I added a google drive link to download the file that I was showing has this problem.

Comment: OK I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Had a look at your file, and I see that the straighter segments are  BSpline paths, which means they have a path effect, and are not just regular paths.

You can see this in the Path Effects panel when you select one of these paths.

[image]

What you can do is convert these to a simple path using *Path > Object to Path*, before you do the joins.

Here's the result, all joined up:

[image]

Comment: That did the trick! Exactly what I was looking for. I hadn't tried converting them into paths because when I selected them, both were labeled as paths (and I haven't run into path effects before). But now I know how to fix it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Fisherck: In 0.92, the path shows as "Path 25 nodes, path effect: BSpline in layer Layer 1", in the status bar. Note that it is always wise to turn such paths with effects to plain paths before trying anything on them.